# Change UIKit Object Anchor Point Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uikit, anchor

I know you can change the origin/anchor point of a UIKit object in interface builder, bout how can I do this programmatically? Or do I have have to simply change position coordinates to be appropriate to the default anchor point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIViews do not have the concept of an anchor point (unlike CALayers). You can position them using the `frame` property or the `center` property. Interface Builder fakes the anchor point and actually stores the UIView's frame coordinates in the nib file.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to change the anchor, just `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and then set the anchor of your view:

```
[[aView layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
```

And the link below is a doc about the layer you may interested in:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html

Comment: I just tried this and it failed to centre the anchor point. I did literally what you did in your example above, except i changed `aView` to my UITextField. Any ideas?

Comment: Each UIView is backed by a CALayer but you will have problems if you try and mix UIView positioning and CALayer positioning. As you have seen things won't behave as you expect. Best to stick to UIView positioning with the frame or center property and adjust your coordinates appropriately.

Comment: The anchor point's default value is (0.5, 0.5), it is centered. The doc I gave can help you, and what @Robin said is right. :) By the way, what you want by centering the UITextField's anchor point? You can just set the frame(which is relative to it's super view) to do the layout.